# Finding a closed formula of a given sum

Tags: combinatorics

I dont understand how to solve this question:

I need to find a closed formula for :

$$\sum_{k=0}^n k\,5^k$$

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
Generalise the question and find a closed form for $$\sum_{k=0}^n kx^k=x\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} kx^{k-1}=x\biggl(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k\biggr)'.$$

Comment: This hint seems to duplicate some of the answers in [this faq version](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn) of the question.

Comment: @T.Bongers: For many students there is a significant difference between the finite and the infinite sum, the former being the more difficult.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Indeed, and at least two of the answers in the post I linked start by computing the explicit closed form for the finite sum. Rather than fragmenting answers over the dozens of times that this question gets asked, I feel it's better to contribute good answers to a *single* thread.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott: The formula is harder to remember in the finite case, but  it's in the curriculum of high school, which the infinite case is not.

Comment: @T.Bongers: Which is fine, if the reader doesn’t get lost in the clutter. It’s fine to refer students to that question, since it does have a nice variety of answers, but it’s also a bit overwhelming, and I do not consider this a duplicate of it.

Comment: @Bernard: In some $40$ years of teaching I don’t think that I ever had a student who had seen the finite case in high school. The finite case of a geometric series, sure, but not this.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott: In France, they have, under the name ‘sum of consecutive terms of a geometric  sequence’, and they have to use it in probability.

Comment: @Bernard: I’m not altogether surprised; the French and U.S. systems have *very* different curricula.

Comment: @Bernard I think it should be $$=x\biggl(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}x^k\biggr)'$$

Comment: @amirali: That's right. I guess I was thinking of the final formula – which I didn't write, and resulted in another of my  *lapsus calami*… 'Tis fixed now. Thank you for warning me!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an elementary approach, without calculus:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^nk5^k&=\sum_{k=1}^nk5^k\\
&\overset{(1)}=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{\ell=1}^k5^k\\
&\overset{(2)}=\sum_{\ell=1}^n\sum_{k=\ell}^n5^k\\
&\overset{(3)}=\sum_{\ell=1}^n\frac{5^{n+1}-5^\ell}{5-1}\\
&=\frac14\sum_{\ell=1}^n\left(5^{n+1}-5^\ell\right)\\
&=\frac14\left(\sum_{\ell=1}^n5^{n+1}-\sum_{\ell=1}^n5^\ell\right)\\
&=\frac14\left(n5^{n+1}-\frac{5^{n+1}-5}{5-1}\right)\\
&=\frac14\left(n5^{n+1}-\frac14\left(5^{n+1}-5\right)\right)\\
&=\frac1{16}\left(4n5^{n+1}-5^{n+1}+5\right)\\
&=\frac5{16}\big((4n-1)5^n+1\big)
\end{align*}$$

$(1)$: The $k=0$ term is $0$ anyway.
$(2)$: Reverse the order of summation.
$(3)$: Sum of a finite geometric series.

The basic idea here is the same as in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/30746/12042) argument for the sum of a similar infinite series.

Comment: Hi Brian, second line of your calculations shouldn't be: $$=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{\ell=1}^k5^{\ell}$$

Comment: @amirali: No: $\ell$ is just a counter to make sure that we add together $k$ copies of $5^k$.

Comment: Oh I got your point. thank you very much for clearing my doubts!

Comment: @amirali: You’re welcome!